# Setting Url Variable for Sub site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I'm trying to create news list system. I wanted to set Url Variable via Javascript and get the item back by id to display details.

Everything went good but when I try to href `/subsite/pages/default.aspx?ID=5` I got error

> Sorry, something went wrong
>   An unexpected error has occurred.

here is the details:

```
    function getUrlParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }          

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var urlParam = getUrlParameter("ID");
    if (urlParam == "" || typeof urlParam == "undefined") {
    getAllNews("LatestNews");

    }else{

        getNewsDetails("LatestNews");
    }


    });


    function getAllNews(listName){
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var lists = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists();
        var oList = lists.getByTitle(listName);
        var collListItem;
        var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(oList);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                // We have the elements
                var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                // It's easy to iterate and get the column values of an item
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var cItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    $('ul.Newscontainer').append('<li class="newsItem"><a href="/news/pages/?ID='+cItem.get_item("ID")+'">'+cItem.get_item("Title")+'</a></li>');

                }

            },
            function (sender, args) {
                //log.log('Error getting list items: ' + args.get_message());
            }
        );
    }


    function getNewsDetails(listName){


        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var lists = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists();
        var oList = lists.getByTitle(listName);
        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(getUrlParameter("ID"));
        clientContext.load(oList);
        clientContext.load(oListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);


    function onQuerySucceeded() {

        var title = oListItem.get_item("Title");
        var image = oListItem.get_item("Rollup");
        var body = oListItem.get_item("Body");
        var date = oListItem.get_item("created");

        $('.newscontainer').append('<li class="singleNewsItem">'+image+'<h2>'+title+'</h2><span class="date">'+date+'</span><p>'+body+'</p></li>');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question so we have a better understanding of your solution.  I would start by seeing if there is a correlation ID available in your error page and even if there is not - I would look at the ULS and web logs.  I would post anything that may look relevant.

Comment: Typically ID is a reserved query string parameter and Sharepoint gets angry if you try to use it in a manner other than in a disp/edit/view form.

Comment: As Eric says, do not use the work ID as your parameter name

Comment: theres no  correlation ID